# Removing installations done by "make install"

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04

Is there anyway of removing files installed by running the command `make
install`?

Comment: [What's the opposite of 'make install'](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1439950/995714)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The majority of packages that have `make install` also provide a `make uninstall`; this will usually remove package files, but not configuration files, similar to how `apt-get remove` works, in contrast to `apt-get purge`.

This, of course, only works properly if you keep the original package directory or reconfigure it using the same parameters for `--prefix` and such.

Answer (score 7):

On Ubuntu, it's actually pretty easy:

Install CheckInstall:

`sudo aptitude install checkinstall`

Run Make and let checkinstall create a .deb:

`sudo make; sudo checkinstall`

Uninstall the .deb and you're done.

[Ubuntu Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall)

Answer (score 2):

There is no automated way - that is why we have package managers.

You would have to manually go through the Makefile and find the files / directories that it installs and manually remove them.